# Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $8$ such that $f(r)=\frac1r$, for $r=1,2,3,\ldots,9$. Find $\frac1{f(10)}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, solution-verification

**Question:**

> Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $8$ such that $f(r)=\frac1r$, for $r=1,2,3,\ldots,9$. Find $\frac1{f(10)}$.

**My Approach:** We know that $f(r)=\frac1r$, which implies that $$rf(r)-1=0$$
Using the information that $f(r)=\frac1r$, for $r=1,2,3,4...8,9$, we get that $1,2,3,4,5...,8,9$ are roots of the equation $rf(r)-1=0$. Which implies that $$rf(r)-1=(r-1)(r-2)(r-3)(r-4)(r-5)(r-6)(r-7)(r-8)(r-9)$$.
Putting $r=10$ in the above equation, we get, $$f(10)=\frac{1+9!}{10}$$ and $\frac{1}{f(10)}$ as $$\frac{1}{f(10)}=\frac{10}{1+9!}$$. But the answer is 5. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right that $rf(r)-1$ is a polynomial of degree $9$ with zeros at $1, 2, \ldots, 9$. But that determines the polynomial only up to a constant factor, i.e.
$$
rf(r)-1=C(r-1)(r-2)(r-3)(r-4)(r-5)(r-6)(r-7)(r-8)(r-9)
$$
for some constant $C$ (which can be determined by setting $r=0$).

Comment: But why is that required? I mean, that is it true for every problem of this sort?

Comment: @GeneralKenobi: Your conclusion $rf(1)-1=(r-1)\cdots(r-9)$ is wrong because there can be constant factor. That factor has to be determined to solve the problem. – It is not clear to me what you mean with “every problem of this sort”.

Comment: I mean that does every problem that relates to finding out a function require finding out the constant factor? Or are there particular question in which we find out that a constant factor is needed?

Comment: It is general for any polynomial. If you have a polynomial of degree N and if you know its N roots, then this the polynomial must have the form $P(x)=C\cdot(x-x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_N)$. You simply assumed that $C=1$ for no good reason.

Comment: @GeneralKenobi: *“every problem that relates to finding out a function”* is too general to be answered. For every problem you have to collect sufficient information in order to solve it. Here you have a polynomial which is uniquely determined by its zeros *and* the leading coefficient.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In your problem $C = \frac{1}{9!}$. Solving your equation gives you $5$. So the answer is true.